# How to convert geospatial Point(lat,lon) hash back to lat lon values?

Tags: solr, geospatial, solr4

My question is related to Solr and facet queries.

I am new to using Solr and using it with tweet records. My aim is to plot number of tweets originating from a unique Point(Latitude,Longitude). I am getting individual facet count results for unique Point ("pgeom"), but the returned value is garbled as it's hash representation of the stored Point data. How can this hash be converted back to usable Point? Please see the details below.

#### Existing fields in the dataset:

pgeom : Point geo spacial. Example: "pgeom":"POINT(13.13735209 -4.2170403)"

lon : Longitude. Example: "lon":13.13735209

lat : Latitude. Example: "lat":-4.2170403}

#### Example of query parameters:

Here i am trying to get individual tweet counts using facet field query on all three "lat", "lon" and "pgeom".

?q=*%3A*&facet=true&fl=lat,lon,pgeom&facet.field=pgeom&facet.field=lat&facet.field=lon

#### Json Result:

"pgeom" facet query results in hash values of ingested Points with associated counts. Where as "lat" and "lon" results in individual tweet counts associated with each of latitudes and longitudes. I would like to use this "pgeom" hash to represent tweets from a location on google map.

point geo spacial:

```
"pgeom":[
    "s",5931,
    "sfju",361,
    "sx",336,
        .. and so on
```

longitude:

```
"lon":[
    "9.6017436",361,
    "6.807174",195,
    "9.28786844",167,
    "5.4770747",169,
    "9.03439492",112,
         .. and so on
```

latitude:

```
"lat":[
    "4.450025",361,
    "9.420721",195,
    "1.29138702",167,
    "8.6851517",169,
    "0.97996991",157,
        .. and so on
```

Response Header:

```
"responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":990,
"params":{
  "facet":"true",
  "fl":"lat,lon,pgeom",
  "indent":"on",
  "start":"200",
  "q":"*:*",
  "facet.field":["lat",
    "lon",
    "pgeom"],
  "wt":"json",
  "rows":"200"}},
```

Response:

```
"response":{"numFound":2034074,"start":200,"docs":[
  {
    "pgeom":"POINT(13.13735209 -4.2170403)",
    "lon":13.13735209,
    "lat":-4.2170403},
  {
    "pgeom":"POINT(18.284989 -8.731565)",
    "lon":18.284989,
    "lat":-8.731565},
  {
        .. and so on
```

How to convert values like "s", "sxp", "sfju" to readable/usable format say Point(12.041015625, 42.01171875) for "sfju"?

Thanks a lot for your time.
lalan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on David's input and a follow up discussion with my colleagues. We found that the Solr field containing geo-location, in our case "pgeom", has to be configured to use a PrefixTree based class. As explained in the following page:

[Solr Spatial Search - PrefixTree](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4)

Once the Solr field, in this case "pgeom" field, is configured to use "location_rpt" type, which uses PrefixTree (class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType").

```
<field name="pgeom"  type="location_rpt"  indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true" />
```

Once we have the list that contains all of the "pgeom" facet results, each of the geohash values can be decoded into individual lat lon pairs using some of the libraries listed under 'External Links' on [Geohash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash). I have used one of the unlisted libraries [python-geohash](https://code.google.com/p/python-geohash/)

```
>>> import geohash
>>> print 'geohash for 42.5, -4.0:', geohash.encode(42.5,-4.0)
geohash for 42.5, -4.0: ezt1ubzk3npz
>>> print 'coordintate for geohash s', geohash.decode('s')
coordintate for geohash s (22.5, 22.5)
>>> print 'coordintate for geohash sfju', geohash.decode('sfju')
coordintate for geohash sfju (12.041015625, 42.01171875)
>>>
```

Cross-check geohash decoding quickly: [Example1](http://geohash.org/sfju) [Example2](http://geohash.org/s)

Also, a new find was to use [Facet.limit](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.limit) to limit the facet field count in the response.

Thanks a lot David. :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your specific question is for you to index full-length [geohashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) to the precision you desire.  No matter what your programming language of choice is, I'm sure you can find a library of code snippet to convert back & forth.  Index it as string and facet on it.

You are then faced with how to plot what could be a ridiculous number of points on a map in a scalable manner.  You'll have to use spatial clustering / heat-map.  See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialClustering

Comment: Thanks for your time. So I guess, there isn't a way to get the desired results without modifying server setup. For now, I don't need to plot all of the points, just the top 200 - highest tweet counts within a region defined by facet.range on lat,lon say lat:[10.0 to 20.0] and lon:[20.0 to 30.0].

Comment: There is no getting around the need to decode a geohash from the faceting area.  This is hardly a big deal; you can surely find code to do this simple task.  For example if your client is the browser then do it in Javascript: https://github.com/davetroy/geohash-js/blob/master/geohash.js